# OSerror when attempting to run Google Colab Deforum Stable Diffusion 0.7

Tags: google-colaboratory, oserror, stable-diffusion

[oserror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oeAW7.png)OSerror when attempting to run Google Colab Deforum Stable Diffusion 0.7. It worked previously, but sudden it is not working. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Q3DP.png)

i tried many times, different browser, can't worked. Could someone help me with it please?

Answer (score 1):

Pytorch and torchvision were updated, you need to re-install previous versions (I couldn't find why the helpers won't work anymore with the render). For now, run before everything:

!pip install torch==1.13.1 torchvision==0.14.1